# Webservice para aplicativo Android

Tags: android, web-service

Preciso desenvolver um aplicativo na plataforma Android. Para tal, a aplicação deverá ser acessada através de um Webservice. A pergunta é: as tabelas do banco de dados do meu aplicativo, para cadastro de usuario, etc., podem ser feitas em MYSQL e hospedadas em um servidor e acessar esses dados pelo aplicativo? Como diferentes usuários podem manter as informações atualizadas? Dessa maneira, preciso utilizar também o SQLite?

Comment: Sim, sem nenhum problema. Pode ser usado somente um banco no lado do servidor, um banco do lado do cliente, ou os dois juntos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As tabelas do banco de dados do meu aplicativo, para cadastro de
>   usuario, etc., podem ser feitas em MYSQL e hospedadas em um servidor e
>   acessar esses dados pelo aplicativo?

Sim, podem sem feitas em MySQL. Na verdade a base de dados utilizada para armazenamento e acesso dos dados no lado servidor é indiferente; e a decisão de escolha entre uma "marca" e outra varia conforme a necessidade do projeto.

> Dessa maneira, preciso utilizar também o SQLite?

Depende. Se você pensa em desenvolver algum mecanismo para guardar em cache os dados capturados a partir do servidor, o SQlite pode ser muito útil.

> Como diferentes usuários podem manter as informações atualizadas?

Esta pergunta é pouco difícil de responder por ser um tanto ampla. Depende das tuas regras de negócio. Se o teu sistema fosse um sistema de voto, por exemplo, os usuários manteriam os dados atualizados conforme dessem seu voto. Daí poderia se obter em tempo real informações sobre quem estaria ganhando a votação.

Answer (score 0):

A geração dos dados podem ser feitas pelo aplicativo e guardadas em um servidor MySql, PHP, APS, Java, tanto faz.

Você pode até guardar esses dados para não ter que ficar fazendo requisições ao servidor toda vez que precisar deles, mas como você precisa mantê-los atualizados, então faça um trabalho só :)